# Выровнять данные в консоли Java SE

Tags: java, алгоритм

Здравствуйте.

Хочу сделать красивый вывод данных в консоли одного проекта. Необходимо сделать выравнивание по колонке, т.е чтобы Имена под именами были и т.п.

По коду, просто переопределение toString() + табуляция.

Сейчас выглядит так: 
[image: вывод]

Comment: \t  горизонтальная табуляция
\v  вертикальная табуляция

Answer (score 2):

При выводе в консоль просто [задайте ширину колонок](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

```
for (Person person : personsList) {
    System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s %-10s %-15s %d", person.getLastName(),
       person.getFirstName(), person.getPatronymic(), person.getTitle(), person.getYear());
    System.out.println();
}
```

Можно и переопределением `toString()`, тогда используйте метод [String.format()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) вместо `printf()`.